# Cannot start docker under circus

Tags: docker, circusd

If I run `sudo docker start redis`, docker starts. But if I run `sudo circusd --daemon circus.ini`, it doesn't start.

circus.ini

```
[watcher:redis]
cmd = docker start redis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker start` command starts a container *and then exits*, whereas a process supervisor like Circus expects your process to stay in the foreground as long as it is running.  You would probably get the behavior you want if you were to add the `--attach` argument:

```
cmd = docker start --attach redis
```

This will cause the client to attach to the redis container rather than exiting immediately.